# Printing to 3 significant figures in python

Tags: python-3.x

my first day learning to code. Have to get my answer to be 3 significant figures in my sample code. Any ideas how to do it?

```
def M(m,p,V,R,T):
Molar_Mass= m/p/V*R*T
return(Molar_Mass)

print(M(4.2,8*10**4,1*10**-3,8.31,300))
130.8825
```